# Horizontal symmetry plane of cis-dichloroosmiumtetracarbonyl

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, symmetry

Consider the molecule $\ce{Os(CO)4Cl2}$ with a drawing given below via [Chemtube3d](http://www.chemtube3d.com/Sym-C2VOs(CO)4Cl2.htm):

[image: Symmetry elements of Os(CO)4Cl2]

I thought in this molecule, if I drew a horizontal plane, then a $σ_\mathrm{h}$ would be present i.e. *A ‘horizontal’ mirror plane is perpendicular to the principle axes* seeing as the mirror would, in my view, cut the atoms in half so the top would be the reflection of the bottom.

However, my professor said in a lecture that this molecule shown here does not have $σ_\mathrm{h}$ and I'm slightly puzzled as to why.

Why does this molecule not have $σ_\mathrm{h}$ plane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compound has only one proper axis of rotation and it is $C_2$ as shown in the diagram. Therefore, it is the principle axis of rotation. By definition, $\sigma_\mathrm{h}$ is a plane of symmetry perpendicular to the principle axis of rotation. However, the plain you were talking about is paralleled to the principle axis of rotation. Thus, it is not a $\sigma_\mathrm{h}$ plane. Nonetheless, it is a $\sigma_\mathrm{v}$ plane, by definition.